# Link to .HTM document will not open within HTML pop-up within Google Earth

Tags: html, hyperlink, kml, google-earth, arcmap

Within ArcMap, I have created KML's from various shapefiles with an attribute/column containting the location of an HTM document related to a particular point.

When I test the HTML pop-up via the verify button in ArcMap it works great. It opens the linked document just fine.
When I simply type out the link in word pad and save as .htm, the link works fine as well e.g.

> *test link*

When I have this identical link in the pop-up window of a specific placemark in Google Earth, the document won't open.  The text is blue signifying a hyperlink but when clicked nothing happens.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post your Placemark element?

Answer (score 0):

Google Earth has security enabled by default and won't allow arbitrary KML to access user files unless explicitly requested.

Under the Tools/Options menu of Google Earth click the General tab then check '*Allow access to local files and personal data*'. Then you should be allowed to access the local files.

It's easiest to keep linked files relative to location of the KML file because absolute URLs can be burdensome. Also there are some issues in older versions of Google Earth if you have whitespace or special characters in the file names or paths.